# DataSource connection to a custom jdbc connection succeeds with wrong details

Tags: java, database, jdbc

I am currently trying to establish a connection to a custom JDBC URL(here JIRA in my case). I have downloaded the jars for JIRA drivers(cdata.jdbc.jira.jar) and placed it in the required directory.

The key thing I observe here is the connection is successful even with wrong details.

```
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:jira:Url=random.com","abc","pass");
```

Can someone tell me where I am missing?

Comment: Hi @DipakDey - have you considered using [Connection#isValid()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#isValid(int)) to see if it's okay?

Comment: How are you checking the connection is successful? Do you have this code inside a try catch block with an empty catch block? Post the complete code.

Answer (score -1):

Could you try with this code?

```java
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:jira://random.com","abc","pass");
```

I don't think `Url=` is correct syntax

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

I think there is some issue with the driver which you have installed. However, as a workaround, we can do executeQuery() on top of the connection to verify the connection.

```java
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:jira:Url=random.com","abc","pass");
Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
stmt.executeQuery("select * from DUMMY_TABLE;"); 
//Please use preparedStatement to avoid SQL attacks.
```

This will throw an exception for wrong details.